# Proper sleep quality index for compare with heart rate patterns

Tags: sleep, practice-of-medicine, heart-rate, shape-form-pattern

I LIKE TO KNOW ABOUT how to compare result of some detected patters in heart rate for sleep quality,for something like [this work](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W06G0RjFKfoHxavuXeJTQncZBmVm8CRqEjmIBVpjpN0/edit?usp=sharing):

[Image-based sleep motion and Slope detection on Hammock, hill and Downward Slope of resting heart rate, for Stroke Patient.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W06G0RjFKfoHxavuXeJTQncZBmVm8CRqEjmIBVpjpN0/edit?usp=sharing)

Based of [this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceJsd.png) some patterns like hammock, Downward Slope and hill pattern Detecting in resting heart rate (RHR) could detect sleep quality like this:

[image]

So i have some recorded [database form **Physionet**](https://physionet.org/content/shhpsgdb/1.0.0/) about heart data during a sleep like this:

[image]

which i can detect heart rate form them, so based of that i can detect detect those patterns but for comparing them with some index like Pittsburgh Sleep Quality Index.

[image]

So,i don't know what is best **sleep quality index** for this compare usage? (like **[Pittsburgh Sleep Quality Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittsburgh_Sleep_Quality_Index)**, [**Epworth Sleepiness Scale**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epworth_Sleepiness_Scale) or ETC)

Thanks.